# How can I have my previous code through rollback on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, server

I have a problem with my app when I uploaded it on heroku, I used the rollback to go back to a previous version without errors and it seems to be fine when I give it open app.

However, the code in pycharm shows the same errors, and if I commit, I get the errors of the latest version as if the code does not have the previous version, can I do something to recover that code?

Comment: Rolling back on Heroku won't have any impact on your local machine, and that's a very good thing. Check out the old branch or commit.

Comment: mmm but with that I don't return to my original local code right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you previously deployed from commit `abcd1234` and you still have a local branch there, check it out. If not, create one. This has nothing to do with Heroku; it's version control. A version control tutorial is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but you might want to find one and go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rollback to whatever previous version you like and then use

```
heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME
```

to get your code back.